# Spring namespaces and placeholder in springs.schemas

Tags: spring, junit, xsd

[Spring-namespaces](http://bit.ly/LZrBXY) allows you to define your own structure how spring beans could be configured. Very cool.

I have to use a 3rd party software (Assentis Docbase) which defines in its spring.schemas the following (example below simplified)

```
http\://com.apress.prospring2/ch07/custom.xsd=custDir:/custom.xsd
```

Meaning: If user defines in its spring-xml with schema-location: "http://com.apress.prospring2/ch07/custom.xsd" spring will validate this file against custom.xsd.

custDir is a directory OUTSIDE the provided jar. Does anyone have an idea how I can set this custDir to point to a valid path during junit test? I already tried -DcustDir=/pathToXsd/ but it did not work.

If I remove custDir than everything works as expected, but I can not remove it from provided spring.schemas since it is 3rd party software.

Maybe this is an issue how property-files are handled in java but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of `spring.schemas` I provided in my question is a properitary definition of 3.rd party software. They implemented there own `EntityResolver` which manually reacts on `"custDir:"` and starts some magic algorithm. So I came to the following workaround.

You have to create your own `my_spring.schemas` which must be live in `META-INF/`. Than you have to make sure that spring loads `my_spring.schemas` and NOT `spring.schemas`.

I achieved it with implementing my own `TestingContext` which is a subclass of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. In `TestingContext` I overwrote method `protected void loadBeanDefinitions(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws IOException` and filled it with implementation from `org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext`. The only change I made was to line `beanDefinitionReader.setEntityResolver(new ResourceEntityResolver(this))` to `beanDefinitionReader.setEntityResolver(new PluggableSchemaResolver(getClassLoader(), "META-INF/my_spring.schemas)`. And voila if I use `TestingContext` my own `my_spring.schemas` is loaded.

Drawback with this solution is that you have to provide all xsd in your jar because the default name, where spring looks up definitions has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to "override" this entry by providing your own custom spring.schemas file with the same entry but with a location to your custom xsd file. The catch is that this is highly dependent on the order in which the spring.schemas are loaded up, but could be worth a try.

Since custDir is not a place holder, you cannot replace it the way you are doing it, I am surprised that the third party schema location is outside of the classpath.

Comment: I tried to "override" it with my own spring.schemas but it did not work TOGETHER with other jar. If I removed the other jar it worked fine. Maybe it is not allowed to have multiple entries for one schema-location in all your spring.schemas :-(